# Removing the textarea border in HTML

Tags: html, css, textarea, border

I'm working with the `textarea` element in HTML and want to remove the border of the box. I also want to align the text in the bottom of my `textarea`.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
textarea {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: That won't remove the scroll buttons in IE.  My solution should cover that.

Answer (score 56):

In CSS:

```
  textarea { 
    border-style: none; 
    border-color: Transparent; 
    overflow: auto;        
  }
```

Comment: @Jacob is it possible to include how to do this directly inside the `<textarea>` tag itself?

Comment: @user5783745: you can just put it in a `style` attribute: `<textarea style="border-tyle: none; border-color: Transparent; overflow: auto"></textarea>`

Answer (score 5):

This one is great:

```
<style type="text/css">
textarea.test
{  
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-color: Transparent;     
}
</style>
<textarea class="test"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can remove the resize icon

```
textarea {resize:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textarea {
border: 0;
overflow: auto; }
```

less CSS ^
you can't align the text to the bottom unfortunately.